# Difference between zero knowledge succint non interactive of knowledge proof (zk snarks) and zero knowledge range proofs (zkrp)

Tags: zksnark

What are the differences between between zero knowledge succint non interactive of knowledge proof (zk snarks) and zero knowledge range proofs (zkrp) ?

Answer (score 2):

A very good explanation from [ING's paper on ZKRP](https://www.ingwb.com/media/2122048/zero-knowledge-range-proof-whitepaper.pdf):

> ZK-SNARKS, are a ZKP-variant, that requires no interaction necessary between the prover and verifier. The most appealing example of ZK-SNARK is its ap- plication in Zcash [8]. Also, Ethereums Metropolis will introduce ZK-SNARKS. This shows that ZK-SNARKS can, indeed, be applied in practice.
>
> ZK-SNARKS are generic; they can verify any function which is particularly relevant for Ethereum which provides the Turing-complete EVM, allowing devel- opers to build any type of logic. Generic ZKPs like ZK-SNARKS, however come at a price. They are notably less efficient than specific zero-knowledge proofs.
>
> [...]
>
> Zero-Knowledge Range Proofs (ZKRP) allow for proofing that a number lies within a certain range.

Proofing that a number lies within a certain range is a more specific ZKP solution, which can be implemented more efficiently (-> gas usage) than the generic ZK-SNARKS.